# SQL fetch value from table

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli

I am trying to write a function that would get a value from a table in my database. I successfully can save a value, but now I have trouble with this.

I have a table called Response where I have multiple columns. One of them is a column called processed, but I would like this to work for any column.

```
function fetch($columnName, $senderID){
    $qry = "SELECT '$columnName' FROM Response WHERE senderID = '$senderID'";
    $conn = $this->connect();

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    if ($result = $conn->query($qry) === TRUE) {
        return $result;
    }
    $conn->close();
}
```

Then I'd like to get the database value into a variable

```
 $val = $db->fetch('processed', $senderID);
```

But my code does not work. When I try to check what is saved in $val, I get nothing.

Comment: Why are you putting quotes around the column name?

Comment: Remove quotes arround column name and $senderID, use the concat operator

Comment: Looks like your using your function wrong try $db->fetch($senderID, 'processed');

Comment: I saw the quotes being used somewhere. I will delete them and see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is when you use

```
$result = $conn->query($qry) === TRUE
```

you are checking whether query return `TRUE`, but what you actually got was `true`. Therefore your condition will always be false. So changing it to

```
$result = $conn->query($qry) == TRUE
```

will do the trick.

Using `===` comparison operator means that the value should be identical in all ways to what you defined.

You can use `==` comparison operator to check whether the value is equal to the given value or not.

Comment: I am sorry I accidentally switched those while I was typing the $val here. In code it is in the correct order but it still does not work

Comment: No, it is not. I have class called _Database_ in one file. Then in the file where I am calling it (where _$val = $db->fetch..._ is located) i _include "filewithdatabase";_ and then use $db = new database();

I use the same process to add a database record, I have a function called _save_ and it works. I am calling it a few lines above _$val = $db->fetch..._ So the files are linked correctly

Comment: By trying to get the $val - I am trying to display it right after, but it does not display anything.

Comment: I tried to replace the return $result, and it did not show up. Then I put it on the top and "Working" did show up

Comment: I just noticed that all $sql we tried went into the Else statement if($result ... === TRUE) {...} else {//this code is executed every time}

Comment: I just wanted to say that I really appreciate your help and the time you gave me. This does indeed work.